# ¿Cómo puedo clasificar información de un archivo .txt leído?

Tags: php

Tengo un script donde leo un archivo `.txt`, lo leo correctamente. Hay datos generales en el archivo, ejemplo:

```
nombre: juan perez
direccion: 109
sexo: masculino
Pais: el que sea 
fecha: 2015-10-15
```

La cosa aquí es que después de leer el archivo quiero solamente que se muestren los tres primeros datos que son nombre,dirección y sexo en formato:

> juan perez/109/masculino

estaba pensando en utilizar `split()`, pero soy muy novato. Si alguien me puede guiar, solo me falta esta parte, ya que ya estoy leyendo el archivo. Anexo mi script:

```
<?php
$example = file_get_contents('example.txt');
echo $example;
<br>

$lista = split('nombre:')

?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que file_get_contents lee todo el archivo y lo pasa a una cadena, por lo que el split(que ya no se puede usar, hay que hacerlo con explode) lo haría sobre el texto de todo el archivo. Yo creo que sería mejor leer línea a línea:

```
//Leo el archivo
$archivo = fopen("example.txt", "r");
//Si estoy seguro que son las tres primeras líneas las que quiero leer
//Creo un indice para no leer más
$numeroLineaActual = 0;
//Aqui almacenaré los datos leidos
$datosLeidos = [];
//Voy leyendo línea a línea y solo leo las tres primeras líneas
while($linea = fgets($archivo) && numeroLineaActual < 3){
    //En linea tengo el texto de la linea
    //Separo los valores usando :
    $partesLinea = explode(":", $linea);
    //Ahora en $partesLinea[1] tendría la parte posterior a los dos puntos
    $datosLeidos[] = $partesLinea[1];
    $numeroLineaActual++;
}
//Ahora puedes juntar los datos leidos con un implode y poniendo entre ellos una //barra o simplemente imprimir
print(implode("/", $datosLeidos);
```

Ten en cuenta que he supuesto que son las tres primeras líneas del archivo, si no habría que modificarlo.
Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, probe tu codigo y al solucionar algunos problemas de syntaxis, no me trae los datos que tiene despues del : solo me tae unos, te adjunto img : https://ibb.co/f801NFb